# Case Sensitive SELECT Statement Against Teradata Database

Tags: teradata

I want to make a select NAM, COUNT(*) as cnt on a table, but I want the count to function in case sensitive matter. 
For example, if the NAM attribute has the following 2 values:

```
DEV
dev
```

I would like cnt for each value to be 1 (to have 2 rows in result), and not cnt=2 (to have one row in result).

How can I do this in Teradata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `CASESPECIFIC` on your grouped column:

```
select
NAM (CASESPECIFIC),
count (*)
from
<your table>
group by 1
```

Here's some good [info on this topic](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ch05.075.32.html).